# Differentiating variability and a trend

Tags: discrete-signals

I'll start by mentioning that I have very little experience in signal processing, so my question might be trivial.

I'm working with a signal that represents a patient's blood tests over the course of approximately 5-10 years. I'm looking for a method to assess whether this signal has a trend (i.e. improving, worsening, or un-changeable across the years), or it fluctuates (improving and worsening alternately).

It should be noted that the signal has a limited number of data points (not more than 30-40 probably), and its frequency is unstable (a patient might have performed a single blood test in the first year, no tests in the second year, and then 4 tests in the third year, etc.).

I would be grateful for any insights that may help with this problem.
Thanks!